# I want to add 7 px border to all selected images once and for all only on bottom side

Tags: image

I have a blog of images and i want to add 7 px wide border only on bottom side of all the images(actual image not on web). any one know any batch processor for the same? please help.

Comment: You want to add the border to the actual _images_ and not just add the border to each image on the page displaying them? Your title suggests doing it dynamically (using CSS), but batch suggests doing it "once and for all" by modifying the images.

Comment: Could you specify/tag correctly? Are you trying to do this using batch? Also, accept some answers before people post answers to your questions

Comment: This is easily achieved using ImageMagick together with simple shell commands. Is there some operating system enforcement that prevents you from using these tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Google search returns many results, include [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/). The freeware tool has an option to batch process all images in a folder and add a border to a particular side of the image; see [this makeuseof article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-easy-ways-to-add-borders-to-your-photos/) (scroll down to irfanview) for some screenshots of what it looks like in action.

Comment: I already saw this. but i actual want something that only adds border on bottom side. 7 px white(or any other color) strip at bottom of every image i select.

Comment: This will add a [insert pixel size here] border of any color to just the bottom of an image, unless I'm somehow mistaken.

Comment: Okay, thnks tehsockz. i think i have missed something.